# husky install causes patherror

Tags: node.js, npm, husky, git-husky

I am trying to manually add Husky to my project as described here:
https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/?id=manual

I run `npm install husky --save-dev` and husky is added and installed as a dev dependency as it should be.
Then I try to run `npx husky install` and get the following output:

```
C:\Users\Luka\Projects\zeiterfassung\testneu>npx husky install

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn bash
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Luka\Projects\zeiterfassung\testneu
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn bash ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Luka\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-21T09_32_56_190Z-debug-0.log
```

Complete error log: https://pastebin.com/ypbMCusx

Nothing is blocking npm from accessing the projects folder, all other modules install and work fine.
I even tried this on a different Laptop, and got the same results, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was using **Git shell instead of cmd.**

As for the cause, I am not sure, I also tried cmd in Administrator mode and PowerShell but neither worked.